# How to make division of polynomials with latex?

Tags: math-mode, polynomials

[image]

How to make division of polynomials with latex?

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't usually answer a question with no code/MWE but I have never used `polynom` before so thought I would answer for my own latex growth. The documentation is [contained on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/polynom) and this is the code for all four default styles:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{polynom}
\begin{document}
\polylongdiv{x^3 -2x^2 -5x + 6}{x - 1}
\bigskip
\polylongdiv[style=B]{x^3 -2x^2 -5x + 6}{x - 1}
\newpage
\polylongdiv[style=C]{x^3 -2x^2 -5x + 6}{x - 1}
\bigskip
\polylongdiv[style=D]{x^3 -2x^2 -5x + 6}{x - 1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am not sure how to get it into precisely your format but this is a start.

Comment: +1 | `style=C` would place `(x - 1)` as divisor on the left side of the equation.