# long polynomial division code styleD

Tags: longdivision

how can I write manual long polynomaial division in style D ? because i need to obtain different quotients from the automatically found quotients: like when a is divided by 1-a, then the quotient must be a series expressed by 1+a+a^2+a^3, etc.
i would be greatful if you help me..
thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What do you mean with style D? Can you show an image in your question please?

Comment: Are you referring to the `polynom` package style D similar to [this answer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660530/273733)

Comment: Yes, i am referring to the polynom package style D similar to that answer. Like in this : [link] (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79182/how-to-draw-polynom-division)